# Работа с объектами DOM JS

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть меню из 4 пунктов:

```
<header>
 <nav>
   <ul class="menu">
     <li class="menu-item">Первый пункт</li>
     <li class="menu-item">Третий пункт</li>
     <li class="menu-item">Второй пункт</li>
     <li class="menu-item">Четвертый пункт</li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Хочу при помощи js создать и добавить сюда пятый пункт. 
Создаю его

```
let li = document.createElement('li');
li.classList.add('menu-item');
```

но почему то не получается через appendChild его закинуть к тем 4, подскажите как правильно сделать, элементы для работы я получил через

```
let mn = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item'),
    menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эмм... попробую угадать: Скорее всего вы не знали, что если `let menu = ...getElementsByClassName`, то элемент с этим классом достается по номеру (индексу). 

`menu[0]` — первый такой элемент, `menu[1]` - второй и т.д. Можно туда добавить id вместо класса, чтобы независимо от разметки, всё правильно сработало, через `document.getElementById()`

Рабочий пример:

```js
let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('menu-item');
    li.innerText = 'Пятый пункт';

let menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');

menu[0].appendChild( li );
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul class="menu">
   <li class="menu-item">Первый пункт</li>
   <li class="menu-item">Третий пункт</li>
   <li class="menu-item">Второй пункт</li>
   <li class="menu-item">Четвертый пункт</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Или, `document.querySelector('.menu').appendChild( li );` — оно находит первый такой класс на странице и останавливается. Не смотрит дальше в поисках всех таких классов (обращаю внимание, здесь есть точка перед классом, прямо как в CSS-селекторах, а в get...className - нет её).